# codeigniter - Do I need a Controller for every URL?

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, codeigniter-3

I have a working project on Codeigniter 3. Now I have to build a FAQ page and I had this doubt: do I need a Controller for every URL?

It is, the FAQ page is a static page, but CodeIgniter generally routes URLs to Controllers, like domain/controller/method. But it seems a waste to build a Controller to only load the View.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation and complete the tutorial contained within.  This exercise will help you better understand the basic concepts.  Every URL needs to go someplace and either it's a Controller function or routed to a Controller function.  If you simply want to load a View, then create a single generic Controller that loads the corresponding View based on the requested URL.  There would be no reason to create a bunch of Controllers that all do nothing but load a different View.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html#general-topics

Comment: Did you got solution for this ?

Comment: @VINEETSHARMA I implemented the way you suggested. I was waiting if someone would suggest anything else. I'll accept your answer! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not right way to make controller for every page. Just make one function which shows page by fetching data from database.

1. First of all make a table named pages in your database then save page_content, page_name, permalink for your different pages.
2. Now suppose your default controller is home, make a function in it with name page as below.

   ```
           function pages( $permalink )
           {
               // get page data based on page_name passed in URL
               $this->db->where( array( 'permalink' => $permalink ) );
               $data['page'] = $this->db->get( 'pages' )->result();

               // load view and pass page object to view
               $this->load->view( 'view_file', $data );
           }
   ```
3. Now same function will show different page content based on permalink passed in URL.
4. For example if URL is www.example.com/index.php/home/pages/faq then content of faq page will be shown.